# Inconsistent behavior when placing adjacent video overlays

Tags: ffmpeg

This script uses ffmpeg to overlay a red [1] and blue [2] stream atop a yellow [0] stream. The intent is that the red stream will be exactly adjacent to the blue stream; at frame 1731 the output video should transition immediately from pure red to pure blue:

```
# These values result in a blank frame where the videos join at around 58s
LENGTH=1800
SPLIT_AT=1731

# These values work just fine.
# LENGTH=1800
# SPLIT_AT=2

ffmpeg \
-f lavfi -r 30 -i "color=c=yellow:s=1920x1080" \
-f lavfi -r 30 -i "color=c=990000:s=1920x1080" \
-f lavfi -r 30 -i "color=c=000099:s=1920x1080" \
-filter_complex \
"[1]concat=n=1[red_concat];"\
"[red_concat]tpad=start=0[red_pad];"\
"[0][red_pad]overlay=enable=between(n\,0\,$SPLIT_AT):eof_action=repeat[red_overlay];"\
"[2]concat=n=1[blue_concat];"\
"[blue_concat]tpad=start=$SPLIT_AT[blue_pad];"\
"[red_overlay][blue_pad]overlay=enable=between(n\,$SPLIT_AT\,$LENGTH):eof_action=repeat[blue_overlay];"\
"[blue_overlay]trim=end_frame=$LENGTH[full];" \
 -map "[full]" video.mp4 -y
```

However, what I see is that there is a single *black* frame between the pure red and pure blue. This black seems to be coming from the frames that `tpad` adds.

What I don't understand is why I'm seeing that black frame. As far as I can tell, my uses of `tpad` and `overlay/enable-between` should produce a seamless transition from red to blue. And indeed, if I change the `SPLIT_AT` value to almost anything else I get exactly that; the value 1731 is "special" in some way.

**Can anyone explain what's going on? Maybe more importantly, can anyone reproduce this problem?**

My first thought was that I've got some form of fencepost error in how I'm using tpad or enable-between. However, that doesn't explain why the script works for most values but not 1731. This difference in results feels like there's a rounding error somewhere, but since I'm dealing purely in terms of integer frame numbers, I don't see how I could be introducing them.

A few notes:

- This is a drastically reduced example from a larger video compositing system. Things like the use of `concat` may appear unnecessary, but they're representative of what the larger system is doing.
- I'm using ffmpeg-6.0 installed via homebrew on an M1 macbook